# jQuery image scrolling, selecting and lightbox-like-fx

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a webpage in which I need to realize something that looks like the following sketch: [image: sketch]

As you can see, there are basically two sections:

- a side-block (preferably) on the right that serves as image-thumbnails scroller;
- a contents-block on the left (in my draw) in which there are text parts and an image that is selected from the right side-scroller.

Side scrolling may be achieved by a browser sidebar or (*very much* preferably better) by apposite up/down buttons.
 When clicking on a different image on the side-scroller that image get shown in place of the previous one.
Last thing, clicking the image selected shall make it show in full-size (not larger than browser window anyway) with a lightbox-like-effect.

Anyone know of a jQuery plugin that already provide all this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

Swiper (http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos/) should help you with this, it covers most (if not all with a bit of a creative layout on your part) of the things you're looking for. It's got some very thorough documentation, for the light box behaviour you're looking for - I'd use one of the baked-in methods to create your own event handler.

Comment: Thank you, it seems a nice good start! Gonna look better in it...